# AJAX Request Won't Work on Internal Server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using w3schools to try to understand how simple AJAX requests work and I came across this exercise page:

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_load

I thought it was a simple example of an ajax request, so I copied and pasted the code into a plain ajax.htm file and copied and pasted the txt file it refers to:

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/demo_test.txt

...and saved it as demo_test.txt file it refers to and saved them both in the same folder.  (Keep in mind, I have an Apache server that processes PHP locally with no problem, so I would think a simple request like this would work on my local machine).

However when I click the button locally I get nothing.  Then, when I upload the files to a different server (a "web host") suddenly it works.

So, this works on a webhost and it works at w3schools but it doesn't work locally on my machine in my root folder (where php works without a problem).

I would prefer to not have to upload my code before being able to test whether it works and would rather be able to process everything locally, like I do with PHP.  Is it possible to do this locally or can I only make these requests remotely from my web host?

Why is my machine not processing this code?  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: are you running from file and do you see file:/// and what browser is it? Also check in inspector to see if you have specific errors.

Comment: Dude you have to post relevant code here how your running the code locally

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of reasons you might not be able to load the file locally, but most will have to do with how you're serving the files. If you're using `file://` you're going to run into problems; you said you have an Apache server, but didn't mention whether you were actually serving this site from it.

Have you checked to make sure that the route you're loading via your AJAX call is actually loading properly? E.g. if the ajax file is at your web root (http://local.site/ajax.html) and so is your txt file (http://local.site/demo_test.txt).

In this situation you can also always check your browser's Javascript console to see if you get any errors or if the files are actually loaded correctly. Depending on how you're serving and accessing the various files, you might be getting [CORS errors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) as well.

The simplest solution is to make sure you're running on a local webserver (your Apache) instead of directly viewing files.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into the status of my web server.  All I know is that I have apache turned on, on my local apple computer, and that I am able to process PHP on my local machine in my root folder and upload to a web host with sublime and FTP settings, everything with PHP is going ok.  I don't host web pages from my home computer though, I just use apache to test my code not to host.  I guess I'll just have to test the AJAX stuff remotely for now, until I figure this out.  Thank you for your help though.  Any help is appreciated.